# How to add digits in android pattern lock

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an android app with pattern lock and I want the pattern lock to show digits instead of dots. How is it possible? Below is the source code. The pattern lock is working correctly. But I want to show digits instead of dots.

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private PatternView patternView;
private String patternString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    patternView = (PatternView) findViewById(R.id.patternView);
    patternView.setTactileFeedbackEnabled(false);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ENTER PATTERN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    patternView.setPathColor(Color.BLACK);
    patternView.setDotColor(Color.BLACK);
    patternView.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);


    patternView.setOnPatternDetectedListener(new PatternView.OnPatternDetectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPatternDetected() {
            if (patternString == null) {
                patternString = patternView.getPatternString();

                return;
            }
            if (patternString.equals(patternView.getPatternString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PATTERN CORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PATTERN NOT CORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
}


activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:patternview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.screenlock.MainActivity">

<com.eftimoff.patternview.PatternView
    android:id="@+id/patternView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    patternview:gridColumns="4"
    patternview:gridRows="5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just dig in [into the source](https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview) this doesn't seems to be a functionnality for now. PS : add the library used next time ;) the answer depends on it.

Comment: what is meant by PS ?

Comment: [Post scriptum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postscriptum#English)

Answer (score 0):

You are use custom library and in this https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview library, number functionality is not available. So you can put issue in https://github.com/geftimov/android-patternview/issues for library update.